# Encode Decode int attribute of a class error

Tags: iphone, ios, decode, encode

```
@interface Esame : NSObject{
    NSString *nome;
    int voto;
    int crediti;
    int anno;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nome;


- (id)initWithNome:(NSString*)nome voto:(int)voto crediti:(int)crediti anno:(int)anno;

@end
```

This is my implementation

```
#import "Esame.h"

@implementation Esame

@synthesize nome;


- (id)initWithNome:(NSString*)name voto:(int)voto crediti:(int)crediti anno:(int)anno {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.nome = name;



    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        nome = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"nome"] ;
        voto = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"voto"];
        crediti = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"crediti"];
        anno = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"anno"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    if (nome) [encoder encodeObject:nome forKey:@"nome"];

    if (voto) [encoder encodeInt:voto forKey:@"voto"];
    if (crediti) [encoder encodeInt:crediti forKey:@"crediti"];
    if (anno) [encoder encodeInt:anno forKey:@"anno"];

}


@end
```

I receive same strange error... expecially in the NSString... what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your conditionals before your `encodeInt:`; you should probably always encode all members. Also, you should probably declare that you conform to NSCoding with `@interface Esame : NSObject<NSCoding>`.

If this doesn't work, try posting the error message you're seeing.

Comment: I try it but I get some error... I can store the array... but when I try to read it I can see that the new array has got 1 element (correct) but when I try to access to it I get this error. *** -[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x796c450

Comment: That issue is caused by this line of code: `nome = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"nome"] ;`. You're not retaining the string returned by the decode. You should use `self.nome = ...` instead to retain this string, or call `retain` manually.

Comment: It works! Thank you... But I don't understand why! Can you explain me the use of the self in this case? thanks

Comment: Last question... In another class I declared a item of type Esame but I can't use for example e1.voto or e1.crediti ... because they are int attributes... how can I fix this issue? thanks

Comment: It worked because if you hold a reference to an object, you need to call `retain` on it. Using the property setter (`self.nome =...`, which is the same as `[self setNome:...]`) retains the object for you (because you've specified the property to be retain in your `@property` declaration). If you specify properties for your other members, you will be able to access them similarly.

Comment: can I do that for an Int attribute?

Comment: You can do it for int attributes. I'm sure searching around for information on properties and your error will provide useful results.